# Whipped egg whites in Gnocchi?

Tags: potatoes, egg-whites, gnocchi

I have been wondering what would happen if I tried to make Gnocchi with whipped egg whites instead of egg. I was imagining it might make them light and fluffier. Has anyone ever tried it?

Answer (score 6):

It's not traditional, [but adding egg white is not unheard of,](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/tyler-florence/perfect-potato-gnocchi-recipe) though in this example, it is not whipped.  There are recipes for gnocchi with whole egg, egg yolk only, and no egg as well.  It might contribute to fluffiness, but it also might throw off the consistency of the dough.  As you do some research on gnocchi, you will note several other variables that impact the consistency of the final product...type of potato and how it is treated, amount of flour, kneading/mixing time...egg or no egg.  It's certainly worth an experiment, and it is not unheard of for posters to do the legwork to answer their own question.  Try it out.  Let us know the result.

Comment: I was planning on trying it out but asked the question to see if anyone else had ever tried it, thanks for your response!

Answer (score 6):

I finally tried adding whipped egg whites to Gnocchi. The result? It was a triumph but needed careful handling.

I whipped an egg white to soft peaks then put my potato through a ricer. Then incorporated the egg white to the potato and it worked great. Then I added just enough flour to make a Gnocchi roll. I cut it into single pieces with a dough cutter and then refrigerated until time to cook.

When cooking, the first time I cooked too long and they fell apart. Then I tried it again and as soon as they floated I took them out and drained them, they were so light and fluffy I couldn't believe it.

You should try this if you like Gnocchi, it's really good but keep an eye when you boil them.

Comment: I love experimental answers like this :) Thanks for including a good description of the process, and possible failures!